# Oracle Get Average of Duration From Subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

Good day everyone, I am a newbie to Oracle SQL. What I am trying to do here is to get average from a sub query of that I made. Here Here are the query:-

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE) + (GATEIN_TIME_START - GATEIN_TIME_END), 'hh24:mi:ss' )as duration
FROM GATE_PASS LEFT JOIN GATE_LANE ON (GATE_PASS_ID = GATE_LANE_PASS_ID)
WHERE (GATEIN_TIME_START BETWEEN TO_DATE ('20171123000000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') 
AND TO_DATE ('20171123005959', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) AND GATE_LANE_NO = 'GATE_1'
```

Above query is work and return rows of data below:-

```
Duration
----------
00:00:50
00:00:17
00:00:13
00:00:43
00:00:43
00:00:37
00:00:18
00:00:17
00:00:18
00:00:18
```

As you can see, I have 10 rows of duration. But, I want to have the average of these duration. Then, I come out below query:-

```
SELECT AVG
     (SELECT TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE) + (GATEIN_TIME_START - GATEIN_TIME_END), 'hh24:mi:ss' )as duration
     FROM GATE_PASS LEFT JOIN GATE_LANE ON (GATE_PASS_ID = GATE_LANE_PASS_ID)
     WHERE (GATEIN_TIME_START BETWEEN TO_DATE ('20171123000000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') 
     AND TO_DATE ('20171123005959', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) AND GATE_LANE_NO = 'GATE_1')as average
FROM GATE_PASS
GROUP BY average
```

As you can see, I made previous query as my sub query into my new created query as to fetch average of these duration. However, I got an error which is:-

```
[Exception, Error code 936, SQLState 42000] ORA-00936: missing expression
```

What is my mistake or am I doing it wrong? Your help are much appreciated.
thank you.

Comment: What result are you expecting? The table structures and sample data to get those durations would be helpful too. (Start is after end?)

Comment: Dear Alex, I am expecting to get minutes or seconds based on difference of GATEIN_TIME_START  and GATEIN_TIME_END. Yesterday I check, most of the time difference are in seconds. Not yet found in minutes. But, @Thangamani Eraniyan solution is what I am looking for. I will update my query that work once I got free time later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Average function should be used for numeric values.

so, subtracting 2 date and time  will return no of days(with fractions in mins), that needed to be convert into minutes and find the average.

Try this..it should work

```
 SELECT  Avg((GATEIN_TIME_START - GATEIN_TIME_END) * 24 * 60 ) as avg_duration
     FROM GATE_PASS 
          LEFT JOIN GATE_LANE ON (GATE_PASS_ID = GATE_LANE_PASS_ID)
     WHERE 
        GATEIN_TIME_START BETWEEN TO_DATE ('20171123000000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')  AND TO_DATE ('20171123005959', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
    AND GATE_LANE_NO = 'GATE_1'
```

I hope this will  work for you.

Comment: I will try your solution later and get back to you once I get the result. thank you for your help

Comment: Doesn't it need to be converted into seconds - so another `* 60` ? To give an average duration of... er... 27.4 seconds?

Comment: Guys, sorry for the late update. Hell of hectic in my office. But I want to say thanks. This query works like a charm. I also add sum() for another calculation and it work just fine. I learn a lot from you guys. Much appreciated for the knowledge and help. God bless! Btw, I will update my working query once I have free time to let you guys know what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

When you subtract two dates you get the difference in days. You can just take the average of that and then use `NUMTODSINTERVAL` to convert the average to an interval data type.

You also do not need to convert the dates from strings as you can use Date literals (i.e. `DATE '2017-11-23'`).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a35c1/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE GATE_PASS (
  GATE_PASS_ID      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  GATEIN_TIME_START DATE,
  GATEIN_TIME_END   DATE
);

CREATE TABLE GATE_LANE (
  GATE_LANE_PASS_ID INTEGER REFERENCES GATE_PASS ( GATE_PASS_ID ),
  GATE_LANE_NO      VARCHAR2(6)
);

INSERT INTO GATE_PASS
SELECT 1, DATE '2017-11-23', DATE '2017-11-23' + INTERVAL '00:00:50' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2017-11-23', DATE '2017-11-23' + INTERVAL '00:00:17' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2017-11-23', DATE '2017-11-23' + INTERVAL '00:00:13' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2017-11-23', DATE '2017-11-23' + INTERVAL '00:00:43' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, DATE '2017-11-23', DATE '2017-11-23' + INTERVAL '00:00:43' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, DATE '2017-11-23', DATE '2017-11-23' + INTERVAL '00:00:37' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, DATE '2017-11-23', DATE '2017-11-23' + INTERVAL '00:00:18' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, DATE '2017-11-23', DATE '2017-11-23' + INTERVAL '00:00:17' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9, DATE '2017-11-23', DATE '2017-11-23' + INTERVAL '00:00:18' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, DATE '2017-11-23', DATE '2017-11-23' + INTERVAL '00:00:18' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO GATE_LANE
SELECT LEVEL, 'GATE_1' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL( 
         AVG( GATEIN_TIME_END - GATEIN_TIME_START ),
         'DAY'
       ) AS duration
FROM   GATE_PASS
       LEFT JOIN GATE_LANE
       ON (GATE_PASS_ID = GATE_LANE_PASS_ID)
WHERE  GATEIN_TIME_START >= DATE '2017-11-23'
AND    GATEIN_TIME_START <  DATE '2017-11-23' + INTERVAL '1' DAY
AND    GATE_LANE_NO = 'GATE_1'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a35c1/3/0)**:

```
|   DURATION |
|------------|
| 0 0:0:27.4 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Extract to get out of different parts and add them up, then calculate average.

```
Select 
avg(extract(second from T.duration)
        + extract(minute from T.duration) * 60
        + extract(hour from T.duration) * 60 * 60
        ) average

from (
    SELECT TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE) + (GATEIN_TIME_START - GATEIN_TIME_END), 'hh24:mi:ss' )as duration
    FROM GATE_PASS LEFT JOIN GATE_LANE ON (GATE_PASS_ID = GATE_LANE_PASS_ID)
    WHERE (GATEIN_TIME_START BETWEEN TO_DATE ('20171123000000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') 
    AND TO_DATE ('20171123005959', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) AND GATE_LANE_NO = 'GATE_1'
) T
```

Comment: The subquery currently generates a string so `extract` will error. Even a date wouldn't work; the subquery would have to generate a timestamp in order to extract time components. And if it's based on `sysdate` then it will have to be adjusted to ignore the current day - though in this case you can probably just drop the day part completely, as long as durations can't exceed 24 hours.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks